# Playframework2 controller testing [Java]

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Have some strange problem when I perform the test of controller in play 2.1.

```
    package controllers;

import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static play.mvc.Http.Status.OK;
import static play.test.Helpers.callAction;
import static play.test.Helpers.charset;
import static play.test.Helpers.contentType;
import static play.test.Helpers.status;

import models.Section;
import models.Topic;

import org.junit.Test;

import play.mvc.Result;

public class TopicsTest extends BaseControllerTest{
    @Test
    public void testCallList() {
        Section s = new Section();
        s.name = "Music section";
        s.id = 1L;
        s.description = "section about music";
        s.save();
        System.out.println(Section.find.where().eq("name", "Music section").findUnique().id); // output 1
        Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Topics.list(1));
        assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
    }
}
```

controller code is realy simple and works on dev. mode just well.
Check it:

```
public static Result list(Long id) {
    return ok(list.render(Section.find.byId(id)));
}
```

Error stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: models.Section.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:66)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1441)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: models.Section.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at views.html.topics.list$.apply(list.template.scala:32)
    at views.html.topics.list$.render(list.template.scala:62)
    at views.html.topics.list.render(list.template.scala)
    at controllers.Topics.list(Topics.java:24)
    at controllers.ref.ReverseTopics$$anonfun$list$3.apply(routes_reverseRouting.scala:761)
    at controllers.ref.ReverseTopics$$anonfun$list$3.apply(routes_reverseRouting.scala:761)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:141)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:31)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:74)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:73)
    at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:420)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
    ... 4 more
```

Please help me to find solution, or fake this test.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more?

Comment: Sure. There is forum app which works in dev. mode. I have a index.scala.html here is sections of my forum(they are stored in db). When u click link of section u go on url "/topics/1", and controller above works(No bad request). But when I try to test this, it fails because of bad request.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting because of the bad request?

Comment: @SlowHarry You should probably wrap your test in a `fakeApplication` with an `inMemoryDatabase()`.

Comment: I do this via inheritance from BaseControllerTest

Comment: I posted error stack trace

Comment: @SlowHarry I once had a similar error, try creating an explicit getter for `name` in your `Section` class to get rid it..

Comment: @Aerus it is not working for me

Comment: @Aerus post it as answer, I write getters for all fields, and it stops failing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play seems to have trouble accessing the fields of your model class(es) (it looks like it's not generating getters and setters). The fairly obvious solution is then to explicitly write your own getters (and setters) so Play can find them no matter what.